# Marshalling a struct containing c-strings

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke, marshalling

I have a C++ struct

```
struct UnmanagedStruct
{
   char* s;
};
```

and a C# struct

```
struct ManagedStruct {
   string s;
}
```

How can I marshal the `UnmanagedStruct`? Do I need to use a StringBuilder?

the C++ library exposes `UnmanagedStruct` getStruct();

Answer (score 1):

**Edit & Correction:** For *return values* of p/invoke calls, the "normal" method doesn't work. I was so used to the normal, `ref`, and `out` behaviors related to method parameters that I assumed return values would work in a similar fashion. Here is the link for a solution to the return value problem:
[PInvoke error when marshalling struct with a string in it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1223690/pinvoke-error-when-marshalling-struct-with-a-string-in-it/1223697#1223697)

You only need to use a `StringBuilder` if you are passing the struct to the C++ method as a byref parameter and the string is a buffer that the method will alter. For a return value, you just need to specify the type of string, which in this case is:

```
struct ManagedStruct
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Lpstr)]
    string s;
}
```

Rememer to add a property to expose the string, since `s` is private here (which is OK, fields should be private).

Comment: There's nothing wrong with making fields public in structs that are used solely for P/Invoke purposes. All accessors would be trivial anyway, and this would not ever change in the future, so why write more code?

Comment: I tried that but I keep getting

Method's type signature is not PInvoke compatible

Comment: Reading the Microsoft help it says

"ANSI strings must be marshaled using an IntPtr and passed as an array of bytes."

Comment: @SteveM, what help? Link, please. Most likely it's for some corner case, not applicable here.

Comment: @Pavel here is the link
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172514.aspx

Also I import the DLL like this

[DllImport("SomeDLL.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
static extern ManagedStruct function( string input );

And inside the DLL the function is

extern "C" UnmanagedStruct __declspec(dllexport) function( char* input );

Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Unless you want ownership of that string passed to C# (letting C# delete it if it likes), UnmanagedType.LPStr is not the right choice.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/799076 for more details.