# WinAPI SendMessage from .NET

Tags: pinvoke, sendmessage

I have an example of winapi code:

```
struct CommunicationInfo {
    long internalMsg;
    const TCHAR * srcModuleName;
    void * info; 
  };
```

...

```
const TCHAR* szText = _T("Hello from my plugin!\n(test message)");
    CommunicationInfo ci = { 0x0401, cszMyPlugin, (void *) szText };
    ::SendMessage( hNppWnd, 0x111, (WPARAM) _T("NppExec.dll"), (LPARAM) &ci );
```

I want make the same call from .net and i wrote such wrapper:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct CommunicationInfo
    {
        public Int64 internalMsg;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
        public StringBuilder srcModuleName;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
        public StringBuilder data;
    };
```

...

```
[DllImport("user32")]
public static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, 
    NppMsg Msg, IntPtr wParam, 
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)] CommunicationInfo communicationInfo);
```

...

```
SendMessage(hNppWnd, 0x111, 
    Marshal.StringToHGlobalUni("NppExec.dll"), 
    new CommunicationInfo 
    { 
        data = new StringBuilder("test test"),
        internalMsg = 0x0401,
        srcModuleName = new StringBuilder("ModuleName")
    });
```

But this code doesn't work. Where did I make a mistake ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Viktor points out, C/C++ `long` is 32 bits in size so needs to be matched with C# `int`. On top of that, the passing of the struct is not handled correctly. In addition the call to `StringToHGlobalUni` leaks since you never call `FreeHGlobal`.

I'd probably handle the marshalling something like this:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet=CharSet.Unicode)]
public struct CommunicationInfo
{
    public int internalMsg;
    public string srcModuleName;
    public string data;
};
....
[DllImport("user32")]
public static extern IntPtr SendMessage(
    IntPtr hWnd, 
    uint Msg, 
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string wParam, 
    ref CommunicationInfo communicationInfo
);
....
CommunicationInfo communicationInfo = new CommunicationInfo 
{ 
    internalMsg = 0x0401,
    srcModuleName = "ModuleName",
    data = "test test"
};
SendMessage(hNppWnd, 0x111, "NppExec.dll", ref communicationInfo);
```

Comment: hNppWnd is a window in the same process that the running code. Anyway your code works fine. Thanks!

Comment: Fine. I just wanted to cover all the bases!

Answer (score 3):

"long" field in CommunicationInfo struct is 32-bit in WinAPI, I believe. So try defining "internalMsg" as System.Int32 in C#

To be sure, try calling printf("%d\n", sizeof(CommunicationInfo)) in C/C++ to know the actual size. If it is (4 + 4 + 4) on a 32-bit system, then the C# struct must also be of 12 byte size.

The "char*" pointer must also be the pointer to unmanaged memory, so the StringBuilder just won't do.

See this [PInvoke error when marshalling struct with a string in it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1223690/pinvoke-error-when-marshalling-struct-with-a-string-in-it) for the marshalling sample

Comment: Попробовал с Int32 - то же самое. А чтобы проверить printf("%d\n", sizeof(CommunicationInfo)) нету компилятора под рукой. в любом случае, зная реальный размер CommunicationInfo, как я смогу задать его через .net ?

Comment: The the  "[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] public StringBuilder srcModuleName;"  also makes a trouble. Try searching the SO for the answer of how to marshal the string pointers. StringBuilder won't help. You have to allocate the unmanaged memory for each of the fields.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1223690/pinvoke-error-when-marshalling-struct-with-a-string-in-it

Comment: Yes, on Windows, `long` is 32 bits in both C and C++ for both 32 and 64 bit processes.

Comment: Just pointed out the problem to the OP. Of course, long is 32-bit on Windows. The list of addressing/int modes is here http://www.unix.org/version2/whatsnew/lp64_wp.html